# Char conversion in gcc

Tags: gcc, casting, char, int

What are the char implicit typecasting rules? The following code gives an awkward output of -172.

```
char x = 200;
char y = 140;
printf("%d", x+y);
```

My guess is that being signed, x is casted into 72, and y is casted into 12, which should give 84 as the answer, which however is not the case as mentioned above. I am using gcc on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The following code gives an awkward output of -172.

The behavior of an overflow is implementation dependent, but visibly in your case (and mine) a `char` has 8 bits and its representation is the complement by 2. So the binary representation of the `unsigned char` 200 and 140 are 11001000 and 10001100, corresponding to the binary representation of the  `signed char` -56 and -116, and `-56 + -116` equals -172 (the `char` are promoted to `int` to do the addition).

Example forcing *x* and *y* to be *signed* whatever the default for `char`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  signed char x = 200;
  signed char y = 140;

  printf("%d %d %d\n", x, y, x+y);
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -Wall c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
-56 -116 -172
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

> My guess is that being signed, x is casted into 72, and y is casted into 12

You supposed the higher bit is removed (11001000 -> 1001000 and 10001100 -> 1100) but this is not the case, contrarily to the IEEE floats using a bit for the sign.

Comment: There is no undefined behavior in this case, since the overflow in the conversion of 200 (resp 140) to `char` is implementation-defined, and in `x+y` the addition takes place between `int` operands according to https://cigix.me/c17#6.3.1.1.p2

Comment: @PascalCuoq I do not speak about the addition, but about the overflow assigning 200 and 140 to signed char having 8 bits

Comment: this one is implementation-defined, not undefined, as I said. “converted” in https://cigix.me/c17#6.5.16.1.p2 and “either the result is
implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised” in https://cigix.me/c17#6.3.1.3.p3

Comment: yes I said wrong using 'undefined', I correct, thank you , my poor english ^^